# HTML calculator

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I am doing a really basic thing. I wrote up this code. I was not able to get the result out of it. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Because I am learning.

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function add(){
    var input1=a;
    var input2=b;
    var result = a+b;
    input1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("t1").value);
    input2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("t2").value);
    document.write("result");
}
</script>
<title>java</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="f1">
        <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1">
        <input type="text" id="t2" name="t2">
        <p>
            <input type="button" id="add" value="add" onClick="function add();">
            <input type="button" id="divide" value="divide" onClick="javascript:function divide();">
            <input type="button" id="subtract" value="subtract" onClick="javascript:function subtract();">
            <input type="button" id="multiply" value="multiply" onClick="javascript:function multiply();">
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't generate the the result.

Comment: variables a and b don't seem to be defined. I think you do the things in the right way...
You want to first get the values `parseInt(..)` and then add then together `document.write(input1+input2)`

Comment: don't `onClick="function add();"`. do `onClick="add()"`.

Answer (score 2):

The result wasn't actually being written, you were writing the string "result".

```
var input1=parseInt(document.getElementById("t1").value);
var input2=parseInt(document.getElementById("t2").value);
var result = input1+input2;
document.write(result);
```

Comment: so I tried document.write(result);

that didn't work. it doesn't add, multiply, divide subtract.

Comment: I would suggest you look into jQuery, and learn the basicas, and how event handlers work. This will let you structure your code in a much better way.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your function as:

```
 function add(){       
    var input1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("t1").value);
    var input2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("t2").value);
    var result = input1+input2;
    document.write(result);
    }
```

Hope This helps

Comment: didn't work, it just generates nothing when i click on the add, multiply or other buttons

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function add(){

   var  input1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("t1").value);
   var  input2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("t2").value);
var result = input1 +input2;
    document.write(result);
}
</script>
<title>java</title>
</head>
<body>

        <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1">
        <input type="text" id="t2" name="t2">
        <p>
            <input type="button" id="add" value="add" onClick="add();">
            <input type="button" id="divide" value="divide" onClick="divide();">
            <input type="button" id="subtract" value="subtract" onClick="subtract();">
            <input type="button" id="multiply" value="multiply" onClick="multiply();">
        </p>

</body>
</html>
```

you can check this on http://htmledit.squarefree.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function add(){

var input1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("t1").value);
var input2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("t2").value);
var result = input1 +input2 ;
document.write(result);
}
</script>
```